# How to identify the CMYK images from image set in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am having a huge set of images in the file. I am trying to check whether the image in RGB or CMYK.

I am trying to this reading the number of channels , as RGB will have 3 channels and CMYK will have 4. But when I try to do it for both of the images, I am seeing Channels as 3 
Below is the code I tried

```
import cv2
readImage = cv2.imread
readImage = cv2.imread(r"TestIMage")
h,w,bpp = np.shape(readImage)
```

Please help me with this. I am ok with other methodologies also to detect the CMYK and RGB images

Comment: Add cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED as an argument in your imread(). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80

Answer (score 2):

The Pillow library makes it very easy to check the mode of an image.

Below is an RGB flower. With pillow, you can open the image and look at the mode attribute of the image.

```
from PIL import Image

rgbImage = Image.open("flower.jpg")
print(rgbImage.mode)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPGtkt.jpg

[image]

Output:

```
RGB
```

Again with a CMYK flower:

```
from PIL import Image

cmykImage = Image.open("cmyk_flower.jpg")
print(cmykImage.mode)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHxUct.jpg

[image]

Output:

```
CMYK
```